# Not able to install gulp-cli globally on Mac

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, frontend, macos-sierra

I am trying to install gulp-cli globally on my Mac but still now working after several tries. It's saying "`-bash: gulp: command not found`"
Also, don't know why its always targetting node v6.11.1 even I remove that version too.
Can anyone please help here?

Mac OS - High Sierra - Version - 10.13.3
After running "`sudo npm install gulp-cli -g`" I am getting the below stuffs

```
/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/gulp -> /Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js
+ gulp-cli@2.0.1
updated 1 package in 18.966s
:~ username$ gulp -v
-bash: gulp: command not found
```

Thanks